# How works nested do until loops?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

i try to loop over columns in two workbooks - from first workbook i need to copy every 4th row, in second workbook i need to paste copied data into new column in second row.

copy every 4th row:

[image: copy every 4th row]

paste it in new column in row2

[image: paste it in new column in row2]
thanks for every help

this is my code what i have:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim b As Integer
x = 6
b = 3
Do Until x < 60
Do Until b < 16
Workbooks("MailTemplate.xlsx").Activate
Cells(x, 2).Copy
Workbooks("Mail2xlsxTemplate.xlsx").Activate
Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial
x = x + 4
Loop
b = b + 1
Loop
```

Comment: you should indent your code and also add parent sheet name references to your calls to Cells. You are also pasting to the same destination each time.

Answer (score 1):

First, your loops will never be executed because the terminating condition is already false before the loops start. `x` is less than 60, so the outer loop never executes, and `b` is less than 16 so, even if the outer loop would be executed, the inner loop will never be executed. Now suppose you make more realstic conditions, then when I properly format your code:

```
Do Until x < 60
    Do Until b < 16
        Workbooks("MailTemplate.xlsx").Activate
        Cells(x, 2).Copy
        Workbooks("Mail2xlsxTemplate.xlsx").Activate
        Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial
        x = x + 4
    Loop
    b = b + 1
Loop
```

you see immediately that `x` is incremented in the inner loop, but the inner loop never terminates because `b` is never incremented in that loop.

That is how `Do Until` loops work, and that is why *you should always properly format your code!*

In your case you may want to use the `Do ... While` loops. This loop will be executed *always* at least one time because the terminating condition is only checkedat the end of the loop body.

Or you can use the `While...Wend` loop, which will only be executed as long as the terminating condition is true, including the fitrst time.

Comment: Hi, thanks yes now i understood actually what mistake i did...i changed it to for loop but still not working as i wish...could you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x As Integer

Dim b As Integer

For x = 6 To 60
  For b = 3 To 16
    Workbooks("MailTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Cells(x, 2).Copy
    x = x + 4
    Workbooks("Mail2xlsxTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial
    b = b + 1
  Next x
Next b
```

Comment: Now Daniela _first format your code_! Use 4 spaces for one indentation.

Comment: Did you know that a for loop auto-increments the loop variable? Lookup `For` in the Visual Basic documentation.